# how to use binder and bind2nd functors?

Tags: c++, functor, bind2nd

How to use binder2nd, bind2nd, and bind1st?
More specifically when to use them and are they necessary?
Also, I'm looking for some examples.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They're never, strictly speaking, *necessary*, as you could always define your own custom functor object; but they're very *convenient* exactly in order to **avoid** having to define custom functors in simple cases.  For example, say you want to count the items in a `std::vector<int>` that are `> 10`. You COULD of course code...:

```
std::count_if(v.begin(), v.end(), gt10())
```

after defining:

```
class gt10: std::unary_function<int, bool>
{
public:
    result_type operator()(argument_type i)
    {
        return (result_type)(i > 10);
    }
};
```

but consider how much more convenient it is to code, instead:

```
std::count_if(v.begin(), v.end(), std::bind1st(std::less<int>(), 10))
```

without any auxiliary functor class needing to be defined!-)

Comment: Right, I understand that, however what about this?
bool IsOdd (int i) { return ((i%2)==1); }

int main () {
  int mycount;

  vector<int> myvector;
  for (int i=1; i<10; i++) myvector.push_back(i); // myvector: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

  mycount = (int) count_if (myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), IsOdd);
  cout << "myvector contains " << mycount  << " odd values.\n";

  return 0;
}
It's from: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/count_if/

They are not defining any functor objects, just a simple function

Comment: Sorry I didn't format the code, but the code is here:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/count_if/

Comment: @Tom, yes, in trivially simple cases the functor can be a function, but, again, you've got to define it previously (often far from the point of use) -- the binders are _convenient_ because they let you avoid that (never _necessary_, as I already said: just _convenient_!-).

Answer (score 1):

Binders are the C++ way of doing [currying](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying). BTW, check out [Boost Bind](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/bind/bind.html) library